# General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, build.gradle

I'm trying to setup firebase for my flutter app and when I try to run this command:`./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` I have this error and the build fails.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\anvay\flutter_project\bookbasket\android\build.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\anvay\flutter_project\bookbasket\android\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by doing these steps:

First of all, close your app if it's running.

Then go to android/app/build.gradle
you will see something like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.my_first_app"
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

replace the 'minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion' with 'minSdkVersion 23' after that save and run.